# Using Prime Faces 3.3.1 Wizard

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

This is the first time I am using prime 3.3.1 with JSF 2.1. I have all the necessary jars for prime faces and I am using the Wizard from their website https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/wizard.xhtml.

Here is my code:

**wizard.xthml:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    lang="en" xml:lang="en" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">


    <h:form>

        <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true" />

        <p:wizard widgetVar="wiz" flowListener="#{userWizard.onFlowProcess}">

            <p:tab id="personal" title="Personal">

                <p:panel header="Personal Details">

                    <h:messages errorClass="error" />

                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value" styleClass="grid">
                        <h:outputText value="Firstname: *" />
                        <p:inputText required="true" label="Firstname" value="#{userWizard.user.firstname}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Lastname: *" />
                        <p:inputText required="true" label="Lastname" value="#{userWizard.user.lastname}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Age: " />
                        <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.age}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Skip to last: " />
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userWizard.skip}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="address" title="Address">
                <p:panel header="Adress Details">

                    <h:messages errorClass="error" />

                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                        <h:outputText value="Street: " />
                        <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.street}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Postal Code: " />
                        <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.postalCode}" />

                        <h:outputText value="City: " />
                        <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.city}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Skip to last: " />
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userWizard.skip}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="contact" title="Contact">
                <p:panel header="Contact Information">

                    <h:messages errorClass="error" />

                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                        <h:outputText value="Email: *" />
                        <p:inputText required="true" label="Email" value="#{userWizard.user.email}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Phone: " />
                        <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.phone}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Additional Info: " />
                        <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.info}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="confirm" title="Confirmation">
                <p:panel header="Confirmation">

                    <h:panelGrid id="confirmation" columns="6">
                        <h:outputText value="Firstname: " />
                        <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel" value="#{userWizard.user.firstname}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Lastname: " />
                        <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel" value="#{userWizard.user.lastname}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Age: " />
                        <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel" value="#{userWizard.user.age}" />>  

                    <h:outputText value="Street: " />
                        <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel" value="#{userWizard.user.street}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Postal Code: " />
                        <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel" value="#{userWizard.user.postalCode}" />

                        <h:outputText value="City: " />
                        <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel" value="#{userWizard.user.city}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Email: " />
                        <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel" value="#{userWizard.user.email}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Phone " />
                        <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel" value="#{userWizard.user.phone}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Info: " />
                        <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel" value="#{userWizard.user.info}" />

                        <h:outputText />
                        <h:outputText />
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="growl" actionListener="#{userWizard.save}" />

                </p:panel>
            </p:tab>

        </p:wizard>

    </h:form>

</div>
```

**UserWizard.java:**

```
package com.verisign.vcc.program.marketing.mbean;

import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.primefaces.event.FlowEvent;

public class UserWizard
{
    private boolean skip;

    public void save(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
        // Persist user
    }

    public boolean isSkip()
    {
        return skip;
    }

    public void setSkip(boolean skip)
    {
        this.skip = skip;
    }

    public String onFlowProcess(FlowEvent event)
    {
        if (skip)
        {
            skip = false; // reset in case user goes back
            return "confirm";
        }
        else
        {
            return event.getNewStep();
        }
    }
}
```

When I access the wizard.xhtml I am getting the wizard with no styles.

[image: wizard.xhtml]

But here is how it is in the prime faces website:

[image: Prime Faces Website wizard.xhtml]

Could you please tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using invalid Facelets markup. You shouldn't use a normal html div tag and stick namespace declarations in it.

For this purpose you should either use a page starting with `html` having `h:head` and `h:body` tags in it or use `ui:composition` for templating.

In the example below, JSF resources and PrimeFaces themes will be added properly.

- XHTML page

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

  <h:head>
  </h:head>

  <h:body>
  <!-- your code here -->
  </h:body>

  </html>
  ```

I hope it helps.